# Advanced concurrency in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

Where can I find concrete examples of advanced CoreData concurrency? By advanced I mean operations on contexts and NSManagedObjects that run simultaneously on two or more threads and every thread can both read and change objects. Each objects saves contexts and listen for changes in another threads, everyone merges changes properly, nothing crashes, there are no inconsistency exceptions, everything is done as it should be.

I read official Apple document about Core Data concurrency, now I'm looking for code examples, tutorials, books, or at least some more detailed information on how to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 4):

there is a really nice blog post from [cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/):

[Multi Context Core Data](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

and i have created a github repo for the Async Saving Example:
[Multi Context Core Data GitHub](https://github.com/carlj/Multi-Context-Core-Data)

Comment: nice but very basic - I need something that creates NSManagedObjects using NSFetchedResults controllers in different threads, passes objects between threads, etc

Comment: did you really read the whole blog post? you should read the "Passing Managed Objects Between Contexts" and "Asynchronous Saving" sections for your questions

Comment: Hi, do you have an updated version of your async saving example? It looks like you are using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification. Isn't it the old way to save merge contexts?